# Rails updating a many to many record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, save

I'm getting stuck at trying to update an existing many to many record.

Project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :assignment
    belongs_to :programmer
end
```

Programmer model:

```
class Programmer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects
    has_many :assignments, :through => :projects
end
```

Assignment model:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects
    has_many :programmers, :through => :projects
end
```

so I have data linked up like so:

```
p = Programmer.create(:name => "Mike")

p.assignments.create(:name => "homework4")

p.assignments[0] = Assignment.find_or_create_by_name("homework1")

p.save
```

so as you can see, I'm trying to update the association of Mike's first hw to "**homework1**". All the homework assignments are already in the assignments table so it shoud just find "**homework1**" and assign it to mike. unfortunately, when I type the third line there are no errors, but it doesn't update it. In memory, `p.assignments == homework1`, but in the DB it's still the same(even after p.save). The project's join table isn't changed at all.

the logs of mysql show this command being generated whenever I enter the 3rd line.

```
SELECT "assignments".* FROM "assignments" WHERE "assignments"."name" = 'homework1' LIMIT 1
```

there's no Update anywhere.... what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

So I found out that I could just reference the join table directly to edit the links. Something along the lines of:

```
proj = p.projects.first

proj.assignment_id = 12
proj.save!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a reference to the object, then you need to edit your migration scripts (db/migrate). An example:

```
def self.up
  create_table :configurations do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.references :project  # This store just the id of the object.
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Don't forget to type:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Surprisingly you don't need a t.references to find the parent or child. My setup above allows me to find any Assignment associated to a programmer and any programmer associated with an assignment.